# Use PHP to parse XML

Tags: php, amazon-ses

Here's an example of my xml data

```
<GetSendStatisticsResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
<GetSendStatisticsResult>
<SendDataPoints>
  <member>
    <DeliveryAttempts>69</DeliveryAttempts>
    <Timestamp>2011-09-12T01:00:00Z</Timestamp>
    <Rejects>0</Rejects>
    <Bounces>0</Bounces>
    <Complaints>0</Complaints>
  </member>
  <member>
    <DeliveryAttempts>1</DeliveryAttempts>
    <Timestamp>2011-09-08T17:00:00Z</Timestamp>
    <Rejects>0</Rejects>
    <Bounces>0</Bounces>
    <Complaints>0</Complaints>
  </member>
  <member>
    <DeliveryAttempts>282</DeliveryAttempts>
    <Timestamp>2011-09-09T18:00:00Z</Timestamp>
    <Rejects>0</Rejects>
    <Bounces>0</Bounces>
    <Complaints>0</Complaints>
  </member>
```

And here's my code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($resp);
$result = $xml->xpath('//member');
foreach($result->member as $member)
    {
    echo "<p>";
    echo "Delivery Attempts: ".$member->DeliveryAttempts."<br/>";
    echo "</p>";
    }
```

But it's failing to work. I'm also OK if $xml is converted into JSON or an Array. Whatever works best to iterate through the xml to display DeliveryAttempts.

Comment: What does `var_dump($result)` produce?

Comment: Says "string(11769) " 1812 2011-09-04T21:23:00Z 0 1 0 105 2011-09-02T00:23:00Z 0 0 0 155 2011-09-02T01:08:00Z 0 0 0 65 2011-09-04T18:53:00Z 0 0 0 1192 2011-09-11T17:08:00Z 0 0 0 1 2011-09-08T00:38:00Z 0 0 0 631 2011-09-04T21:08:00Z 0 0 1 193 2011-09-02T01:23:00Z 0 0 0"...and so on

Comment: If the xml that you posted is all that you have, then it is not valid as far as my knowledge goes. There are no closing tags for SendDataPoints, GetSendStatisticsResult and GetSendStatisticsResponse .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the XML namespace. Do something like this:

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace( 'ses', 'http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/' );
$result = $x->xpath( '//ses:member' ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
foreach ($result as $member) {
   ...
}
```

instead.

Comment: Given your comment above, you've gotten no results from the xpath, so the foreach loop has no data to work on.

Comment: Yes, but as shown above (in both xml and the raw string), the data is there. Something is malformed with the syntax or PHP is fubar.

Comment: No, PHP's not fubar. Most likely your XML isn't being parsed properly and most of it's being dropped on the floor.  Check `libxml_get_errors()` after you do the load.